# MYSQL statement to fetch data from previous day and also from a specific time afterwards

Tags: mysql, datagrip

IN Oracle

```
Select * 
from tablename 
where date_column > TO_DATE(to_char(sysdate-1,'YYYY/MM/DD')||' 19:30:00', 'YYYY/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS')
```

The above query during any time of execution it fetches records from the previous day and afterward of 19.30pm to the current time of the execution.

I need a similar query statement to do it in MYSQL.

Comment: Sample data would greatly help your question.

Comment: ```WHERE date_column > CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL '04:30' HOUR_MINUTE```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM
tablename 
WHERE date_column >= CONCAT(CURDATE()-interval 1 day,' 19:30:00') 
AND date_column <= NOW();
```

[Demo fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=2133ccb1b076e6698d0951bc051cf93a)